# Duplicate content issue on product review page

Tags: url, duplicate-content

I have a product review page that defaults to showing all reviews. On this page I have 5 links which link to showing only the 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 star ratings.

If I have a product with 1 review which is a 5 star review, the 5 star review link then gets flagged for duplicate content as my URL changes from `www.example.com/Review/CODE/0` to `www.example.com/Review/CODE/5`.

But the content doesn't change (as there is only the one review).

My initial thought is to add `no-index` to the review page that lists everything and only allow the search engines to index each star rating page individually.

Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have same content on all the 6 URLs (`www.mysite.com/Review/CODE/0` to `www.mysite.com/Review/CODE/5`) add `rel="canonical"`link to the `<head>` section of all the remaining 5 URLs.

Add `<link rel="canonical" href="www.mysite.com/Review/CODE/0"/>` to the `<head>` section of `www.mysite.com/Review/CODE/1` to `www.mysite.com/Review/CODE/5`.

Comment: I understand what `no-index` does. It should still index the other pages though which have all the reviews on anyway. i.e Don't index the `/0` but go ahead and index `/1`, `/2` etc. That was my thinking. I agree that the canonical option is much better though.

Comment: So the contents on `/1`,`/2` etc will be the same. right?

Comment: I don't actually provide links for those if there are no reviews with those rating values so they couldn't get to that point. It's not a problem, your canonical idea is the correct way, I just forgot about the tag. Thanks for your help.